# Simple trick to turn function declaration into variable definition

Tags: c++, variables, syntax, function-declaration, most-vexing-parse

I know that the following statement is interpreted as a function declaration instead of a variable definition

```
boost::system::system_error sys_err(boost::system::error_code());
```

Is there any simple trick to turn it into a one-liner variable definition which is what I intend? I don't quite like the writing

```
boost::system::system_error sys_err(0, boost::system::system_category());
```

Comment: `std::system_error sys_err{std::error_code()};`

Comment: @Dúthomhas You're correct. My fault not to make my intention clear. I'm actually using Boost, and I don't want my code to have a dependency on C++11.

Comment: The way compilers interpret this ambiguous syntax is called "most vexing parse". On SO we even have a tag for it. If you read the [tag's description](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/most-vexing-parse/info) you can even find the answer to your question! :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dúthomhas' answer will do, provided your compiler supports at least C++11. For a more universal solution you can wrap the argument in a extra pair of parentheses:
`boost::system::system_error sys_err((boost::system::error_code()));`